# Собрать файл из байтов используя только heap

Tags: java, serialize

В `DB` есть файл изображение в виде массива байтов, который нужно отдать клиенту через сервлет. В `nio` есть конструкция в `Files.write(Path, bytes)` при помощи которой можно собрать эти байты обратно в файл и записать на диск, но так как мне все равно отдавать это в сервлет, да и вообще запись куда бы то ни было кроме `DB` заводит меня на территорию сисадмина, хотелось бы сделать это прямо в хипе.

Возможно ли собрать файл перед отправкой клиенту не трогая дисковое пространство? И если да то как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У ответа сервлета есть возможность использовать output stream (servlet.getOutputStream()), который предназначен именно для подобных вещей - можно просто переписывать данные из БД в этот поток. Возможно, потребуются дополнительные телодвижения (скорее всего, после записи первого байта в этот поток уже нельзя будет добавлять заголовки к ответу), но сам по себе этот интерфейс придуман именно для таких вещей - чтобы можно было писать какие-то вещи напрямую и не хранить их в оперативной памяти.

В то же время хочу отметить, что хранение файлов в бд создает значительные проблемы для достижения высокого перформанса (начиная от двойной передачи данных по сети и кончая тем, что nginx и аналоги знает про оптимизации типа zero copy, а у вас в приложении их скорее всего не будет)